# Resource compiling not invoked by qmake

Tags: qt, resources, qmake

There is a way to automatically trigger recompilation of resource files when some of the original resource files (icons, text files, etc.) are changed?

E.g. if I have a .pro file with

```
RESOURCES = something.qrc
```

and in the something.qrc file I have something like

```
   <RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/localfile">
        <file>shaders/mytextfile.fs</file>
    </qresource>
   </RCC>
```

If I change the mytextfile.fs file the generation of the qrc_something.cpp file is not triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to add the variable [DEPENDPATH](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html#dependpath) to your .pro:

```
DEPENDPATH += ./path_to_my_qrc_files
```

It tells QMake where to look for dependencies.  It works for header files, I don't know for resources.  May worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The question is misleading.

Changes of files that a mentioned in the resource file DOES trigger regeneration of qrc_something.cpp file.

I've checked it myself. It just works without any need to edit .pro file.